Power Automate - How to fill Excel cells dynamic?
I have a flow that is triggered every Monday. The flow is supposed to dynamically enter the outputs of my variable into a specific row of my Excel list.
If utcnow matches the current date, it should generate an entry in the respective column. How can I hardcode this?
I would like to fill the cells dynamic.
